# why touch command is not working in perl?

Tags: perl

Could anyone please point out my error

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
my $i;
for $i in {1..10} 
do 
    system("touch file${i}");
done
```

I have saved above in file.pl and did `perl file.pl` and error popping up is

```
Bareword found where operator expected at tr.pl line 4, near "$i in"
        (Missing operator before in?)
syntax error at tr.pl line 4, near "$i in "
```

Even on terminal `touch file{1..10}` doesn't create file1, file2, ...file10 instead it creates file{1..10}.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: This may sound a bit harsh, but you really should read a Perl tutorial/book/whatever instead of guessing the syntax. What you are doing is not a Perl for loop (Perl != Shell).

Comment: try look at [http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/index.html](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/index.html)

Comment: Okay I admit that I was confused and wrote wrong code but could you please tell me why touch isnt working on terminal. @Dada

Comment: @Anthonyj: Your `touch` command works as expected for me (i.e. I get ten files created). I'm using `bash` 4.4.23. It's impossible to help you more without a lot more information (and you should really ask this as a new question with a `bash` tag).

Comment: @ Dave Cross Thanks . I will check my bash version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you're teaching yourself Perl, but your syntax for the loop is wrong. It looks like you're confusing shell scripting with Perl programming.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

# Always add these
use strict;
use warnings;

# Round parens for the "for" list.
# Curly braces to delimit the code block.
for my $i (1..10) {
    system("touch file${i}");
}
```

Comment: Ya may be Im confused . Actually I tried for i in {1..10} ;do touch file${i} ;doneon terminal when it was not working I just copied to file . Thanks .

Comment: Could you please tell why touch isnt working on terminal

Comment: @Anthonyj: Something that you run on the terminal is shell scripting. That is not Perl programming. If you don't understand the difference, then I'm afraid you're **really** confused :-)